# How to map json objects to typescript arrays

Tags: typescript

I have tried various examples but none has worked so far.  I have a GET response as follows:

> {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…},
>   …} config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…},
>   timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}

---

> data:
>
> sales: Array(2) 0:  {Id: 2, Amount: 500, DateCreated: "01/01/2019
>   00:00:00"} 1:  {Id: 3, Amount: 410, DateCreated: "01/20/2019
>   00:00:00"}

I have an interface definition as follows:

```
interface ISales{
  id:number;
  amount:number;
  dateCreated:Date
}
```

I want to create an array and fill in the values from the response sales.  I have tried the following:

```
 const result: ISales = response.data.sales;
      let payments: ISales[];
      payments = [];
      payments.push(result);


payments.map((item)=>{"whole array", console.log(item)})

payments.map((item)=>{"property only", console.log(item.amount)})
```

In the above the whole array displays the data right as

> (2) [{…}, {…}] 0: {Id: 2, Amount: 500, DateCreated: "01/01/2019
>   00:00:00"} 1: {Id: 3, Amount: 410, DateCreated: "01/20/2019 00:00:00"}
>   length: 2
>   **proto**: Array(0)

Whereas the property only is undefined.  What is wrong with my code.  How can I read the property value and store it in payments?

Comment: payment is empty,  set it ->payments = result;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find the error.  The properties in the interface were camel case whereas, those from the response were pascal case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const result: ISales[] = response.data.sales;
result.map((isales: ISales)=>{console.log(isales)});
result.map((isales: ISales)=>{console.log(isales.amount)});
```

Comment: It gives the errorerror: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67569:24 at step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63911:23) at Object.next 
message: "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined↵    at 
__proto__: Error